# Class is not abstract and does not override abstract method...how to add button to java applet?

Tags: java, button, applet, abstract-class, actionlistener

This is my code, the relevant part is:

> public class Fibannacci extends Applet implements ActionListener {

I want to add a button to this code that will allow me to go repaint the Spiral with different colours (randomly select a set of colours).

I get the error:

> Fibannacci is not abstract and does not override abstract method
>   actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent) in
>   java.awt.event.ActionListener

Any help is greatly appreciated! (PS. I'm aware my formatting isn't very good...I'm going back later to fix it later)

```
/**
 * ArcTest is an applet that will randomly select a set of colors to generate a pattern    of colors that will be applied to the Fibannacci Spiral
 * OVERALL: The applet displays the Fibannacci spiral
 * @author Gareth Sykes
 * @version 03/07/2014
 */

import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.Math.*;

public class Fibannacci extends Applet implements ActionListener {

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        int w = getWidth(); // width of screen
        int h = getHeight(); // height of screen

        int rectSide = 1; // F1
        int rectSidePrev = rectSide; // F2: previous square
        int rectX = 5 * w / 8; // X coordinate of a rectangle
        int rectY = 5 * h / 8; // Y coordinate of a rectangle
        int angleStart = 0; // The angle an arc is drawn from
        int DegreesAround = 90; // Degrees around an arbitrary circle

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(6));// Sets thickness of rectangles/arcs
        // drawn

        // Draw a segment of the Fibannacci Spiral
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        // g.drawArc (x, y, rectWidth, rectHeight, StartingAngleANTI-CLOCKWISE,
        // DegreesAroundCircleANTI-CLOCKWISE)
        g.drawArc(rectX - rectSide, rectY, rectSide * 2, rectSide * 2,
                angleStart, DegreesAround);
        angleStart = angleStart + 90;
        g.drawArc(rectX - rectSide, rectY, rectSide * 2, rectSide * 2,
                angleStart, DegreesAround);

        // Draws the first two rectangles
        // g.setColor (Color.black); FOR FUTURE REFERENCE: In the case that the
        // Color of the Rectangle wants to be modified
        g.drawRect(rectX, rectY, rectSide, rectSide);

        g.drawRect(rectX - rectSide, rectY, rectSide, rectSide);

        // Draws the nth rectangles in the fibannacci series
        int n = 0;
        int x = 1;
        int FirstPrevX = 5 * w / 8 - rectSide; // The rectangle previously
        // constructed's X coordinate
        int FirstPrevL = rectSide; // The rectangle previosly constructed's side
        // length
        int FirstPrevY = 5 * h / 8; // The rectangle previously constructed's Y
        // coordinate

        int SecondPrevX = 5 * w / 8; // The rectangle consturcted before the
        // previously constructed rectangles' X
        // coordinate
        int SecondPrevL = rectSide; // The rectangle consturcted before the
        // previously constructed rectangles' side
        // length
        int SecondPrevY = 5 * h / 8; // The rectangle consturcted before the
        // previously constructed rectangles' Y
        // coordinate

        int arcX = FirstPrevX; // The X coordinate of the arc
        int arcY = FirstPrevY; // The Y coordinate of the arc

        // Randomly Generates a pattern of four colors that the the rectangles
        // and arcs will be colored
        int[] color;
        color = new int[5];

        int m = 0;
        boolean dup;

        while (m < 4) {
            dup = false;
            int rn = (int) (Math.random() * 6);
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                if (rn == color[i]) {
                    dup = true;
                }
            }
            if (dup == false) {
                color[m] = rn;
                m = m + 1;
            }
        }

        color[4] = color[0];

        // Randomly picks which set of colors to use for the Fib. Spiral
        int set = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;

        int[] r = new int[7];
        int[] gr = new int[7];
        int[] b = new int[7];

        // NOTE: Three dimensional array?
        switch (set) {
        case (1):
            r = new int[] { 51, 60, 112, 231, 177, 173, 3 };
        gr = new int[] { 26, 87, 112, 235, 189, 202, 92 };
        b = new int[] { 97, 132, 112, 240, 205, 255, 155 };
        break;
        case (2):
            r = new int[] { 237, 255, 254, 155, 58, 230, 112 };
        gr = new int[] { 83, 185, 235, 202, 187, 230, 112 };
        b = new int[] { 20, 42, 81, 62, 201, 230, 112 };
        break;
        case (3):
            r = new int[] { 9, 35, 50, 146, 154, 255, 112 };
        gr = new int[] { 46, 79, 99, 204, 239, 231, 112 };
        b = new int[] { 32, 50, 66, 71, 63, 97, 112 };
        break;
        case (4):
            r = new int[] { 120, 171, 246, 222, 170, 73, 112 };
        gr = new int[] { 120, 170, 235, 206, 128, 43, 112 };
        b = new int[] { 47, 99, 208, 191, 103, 41, 112 };
        break;
        }

        // While loop will draw both rectangles and the Fibannacci Spiral
        while (n < 12) {
            n = n + 1;

            int NextL = FirstPrevL + SecondPrevL; // Side length of Next
            // rectanlge in series

            switch (x) {
            case (1):
                rectX = FirstPrevX;
            rectY = FirstPrevY + rectSide;

            arcX = rectX;
            arcY = rectY - NextL;

            x = x + 1;
            break;
            case (2):
                rectX = FirstPrevX + rectSide;
            rectY = FirstPrevY - SecondPrevL;

            arcX = rectX - NextL;
            arcY = rectY - NextL;

            x = x + 1;
            break;
            case (3):
                rectX = FirstPrevX - SecondPrevL;
            rectY = FirstPrevY - NextL;

            arcX = rectX - NextL;
            arcY = rectY;

            x = x + 1;
            break;
            case (4):
                rectX = FirstPrevX - NextL;

            arcX = rectX;
            arcY = rectY;
            x = 1;

            break;
            }

            g.setColor(new Color(r[color[x]], gr[color[x]], b[color[x]]));
            g.fillRect(rectX, rectY, NextL, NextL); // Draws a rectangle
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawRect(rectX, rectY, NextL, NextL); // Outlines the rectangle

            angleStart = angleStart + 90;

            // re-assigns variables such that they are ready for the next time
            // through the loop
            SecondPrevX = FirstPrevX;
            SecondPrevL = FirstPrevL;
            SecondPrevY = FirstPrevY;
            FirstPrevX = rectX;
            rectSide = NextL;
            FirstPrevL = rectSide;
            FirstPrevY = rectY;

            // Draws a segment of the fibannacci spiral
            g.setColor(new Color(r[color[x - 1]], gr[color[x - 1]],
                    b[color[x - 1]]));
            g.fillArc(arcX, arcY, NextL * 2, NextL * 2, angleStart,
                    DegreesAround);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawArc(arcX, arcY, NextL * 2, NextL * 2, angleStart,
                    DegreesAround);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class claims to implement ActionListener.  This interface requires that you implement actionPerformed.  Something like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
   //code that reacts to the action... 
}
```

See [ActionListener.actionPerformed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html#actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent)) for the javadoc.